# Nodejs req Json size limit

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, post, request

I have a general question regarding to req object in nodeJS. Assume that I have a code that send a data in json format to my sever via ajax post method. Consider a situation that user changes my client code that send infinitely large json file to my server by calling specific link that by default has been designed to have limited json data with specific format. In this case, I want to know how can I prevent such type of hacks happens.

Comment: Well first of all no one will send data on my end without authentication. You also want to look up cross origins request!

Comment: Just add an authentication method, like a token that is required & expires after some time

Answer (score 4):

There are a few way:

1. Add authentication
2. Configure a web server, like Nginx has `client_max_body_size`
3. or use a middleware like [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) which you can set:

   var express    = require('express')
   var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

   var app = express()
   app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '5mb' }))

Comment: Thanks. I tried to test this by setting limit 1byte and sent a long string. Still everything passed and could not get an error regarding to the size.   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}),bodyParser.json({limit: '1b'}));

Comment: Anyone has any idea why  the above solution does not work?

Comment: Can you show me the full code that is not working? mine is working perfectly. Check out the `body-parser' [npm package](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/tree/master/test) page to understand how it works. Make sure you do not initialize the `body-parser' multiple times.